# error ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); When connecting to Radis Data Base, node JS

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to add data to a Redis database
I copied from: https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/tutorials/stack-node
This is my schema:

```
import { Entity, Schema } from 'redis-om'
import client from './client.js'
import { router as person_router, router } from '../routers/person_router.js'




/* our entity */
class Person extends Entity {}
const personSchema = new Schema(
    Person, {
        firstName: {
          type: "string",
        },
        lastName: {
          type: "string",
        },
        age: {
          type: "text",
        },
        pulse_at_rest: { //דופק  במנוחה
          type: "text",
        },
        background_diseases_and_medical_limitations: { //מחלות_רקע ומגבלות_רפואיות
          type: "string",
        },
        Working: { //עבודה
          type: "string",
        },
        password: {
          type: "string",
        },
        Preferred_training_time: {//זמן_אימון_מועדף
          type: "string",
        },
        the_duration_of_the_training: {//משך הריצה
          type: "text",
        },
        goal: { //מטרה
          type: "string",
        },
        gender: {//מין
          type: "text",
        },
        height: {
          type: "text",
        },
        Sports_background: {//רקע_ספורט
          type: "string",
        },
        
      },

      )



      /* use the client to create a Repository just for Persons */
      export const personRepository = client.fetchRepository(personSchema);
      /* create the index for Person */
      personRepository.createIndex().then(data=> {console.log(data)}).catch(err => {console.log("err", err)})

       export default Person
```

And here I use it:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis-om';
import { Client } from 'redis-om';
import { personRepository } from './person';

/* pulls the Redis URL from .env */
const url = process.env.REDIS_URL;

/* create a connection to Redis with redis-om */
export const connection = createClient({ url });
connection.connect();

/* create a Client and bind it to the redis-om connection */
const client = new Client().use(connection);

async function fetchData(id) {
  const person = await personRepository.fetch(id);
  console.log(person); // Log the person data
  return person;
  // Use the person data here
}

(async () => {
  const id = "123455";
  const person = await fetchData(id);
  person.location = { longitude, latitude };
  person.locationUpdated = locationUpdated;
  await personRepository.save(person);

  let keyName = `${person.keyName}:locationHistory`;
  await connection.xAdd(keyName, '*', person.location);
})();

export default client;
```

But when I import the file into the main file:

```
 import { router as personRouter } from './routers/person_router.js'
```

I get

node:internal/errors:490
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hodaya\Downloads\express-redis-om-workshop-main\express-redis-om-workshop-main\om\person' imported from C:\Users\hodaya\Downloads\express-redis-om-workshop-main\express-redis-om-workshop-main\routers\person_router.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Do you know how to solve the problem?
Thank you!

I searched for solutions without success

Comment: Maybe after all?
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: This is a garden variety import error. This just means that the `../routers/person_router.js` file isn't where you think it is. Or doesn't have the name you think it does. What's your directory structure look like?